# Do I need to add every profile to the Apex Classe security?

Tags: apex, security, permissions

I am following the trigger framework explained in this image: [Link](https://krishhari.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/triggerdesign-account-v1-02.jpg)

In this case, Do I need to add every profile to the AccountHelper class security?

My AccountHelper class does not have `with sharing` keyword.

I am little confused here..I know that when we design a VF page, we need to add every profile to the VF page and no need for controller.

In the above case, Do I need to add the profiles to the Apex class security?

Answer (score 2):

Apex class security applies to these use cases (from the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_package_security.htm&language=en_US)):

> You can specify which users can execute methods in a particular
>   top-level Apex class based on their profile or an associated
>   permission set. These permissions only apply to Apex class methods,
>   such as Web service methods, or any method used in a custom
>   Visualforce controller or controller extension applied to a
>   Visualforce page. Triggers always fire on trigger events (such as
>   insert or update), regardless of a user's permissions.

So, for triggers, no need to worry about this

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, it would be wise to add with sharing to the class. Without seeing your code, I can't answer whether or not you need to add the profiles, but somehow I doubt you would based on the fact it would be called in the context of the sharing for VF Page execution that eventually causes it to be called.

For a good discussion on the subject, I'd recommend you read a question I asked [Does "with sharing" only apply to 1st entry point of code?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73392/does-with-sharing-only-apply-to-1st-entry-point-of-code) along with the link in that question to [Without Sharing: Best practices when bypassing Apex sharing rules and object security](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Without_Sharing) and @SFDCFox's answer to my qustion.