# Inherited sharing question in nested inner classes

Tags: apex, sharing, inner-class

The sharing documentation [Using the with sharing, without sharing, and inherited sharing Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) says:

- The sharing setting of the class where the method is defined is applied, not of the class where the method is called. For example, if a method is defined in a class declared with `with sharing` is called by a class declared with `without sharing`, the method executes with sharing rules enforced.
- Both inner classes and outer classes can be declared as `with sharing`. The sharing setting applies to all code contained in the class, including initialization code, constructors, and methods.
- Inner classes do not inherit the sharing setting from their container class.

I have an awkward case where I have `inherited sharing` inner classes called from `with sharing` and `without sharing` inner classes of a different outer class. See a [Clean way to vary sharing at runtime in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291091/clean-way-to-vary-sharing-at-runtime-in-apex) for that code. The aim is for the `with sharing` and `without sharing` to be respected and by my reading of the documentation it should be based on the last bullet point above.

Do you agree? Right now I have some confusing test results...

(A related question is [Sharing rules and Inner classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231495/sharing-rules-and-inner-classes).)

**PS**

I assume that a "Default Internal Access" setting of "Private" is ignored in Apex `without sharing` code but at present my test does not support that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inherited sharing` behaves identically to not using a sharing mode at all, **except** when used as a top-level entry point (e.g. a Visualforce or Aura controller, RestResource, etc), in which case the context of the call will be `with sharing`.

If you care about Security Reviews, you should probably use `inherited sharing` on all classes that do not specify `with sharing` or `without sharing`. Aside from that, inner classes, utility classes, and other non-top-level-execution-context classes can omit the `inherited sharing` keyword, and it will automatically execute in the currently configured sharing mode.

I [answered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/291791/2984) your other question that demonstrates how I would get into a certain sharing mode using a minimal amount of code, most of which is boilerplate at that point.

The documentation makes a good argument for using `inherited sharing` as opposed to no sharing mode at all:

> Apex without a sharing declaration is insecure by default. Designing Apex classes that can run in either with sharing or without sharing mode at runtime is an advanced technique. Such a technique can be difficult to distinguish from one where a specific sharing declaration is accidentally omitted. An explicit inherited sharing declaration makes the intent clear, avoiding ambiguity arising from an omitted declaration or false positives from security analysis tooling.

Using `inherited sharing` makes it clear that the higher-level sharing mode will be respected; the code becomes self-documenting while still respecting your decision on using the calling context's sharing mode.