# Inner Class Without Sharing not working as expected

Tags: apex, sharing, error-messages, inner-class, without-sharing

I found this post ([Sharing rules and Inner classes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231495/sharing-rules-and-inner-classes)), which references documentation that inner classes do not inherit the sharing of their container class.

**From the documentation:**

> Both inner classes and outer classes can be declared as with sharing.
> Inner classes do not inherit the sharing setting from their container
> class. Otherwise, the sharing setting applies to all code contained in
> the class, including initialization code, constructors, and methods.

This makes sense to me, and I was fine with this because I wanted to implement a separate, private inner class anyway specifically designed to bypass sharing in some situations within the service class. I thought that this would be more elegant than creating a separate, dedicated `without sharing` class.

However, in my testing, I'm finding that the end user is still receiving an INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id error when running `new WithoutSharing().updateObjRecords(list)` when they only have read-only access to the objects in question.

The below code is an example of the scenario I'm trying to implement, but sharing seems to still be applied. Am I missing something here? Should this be possible, or am I going to have to create a separate Service class specifically designed as without sharing?

```
public with sharing class ObjectAService {
  public static void updateDaysSinceLastCalled(
    List<OBJ_A__c> objList,
    Map<String, DateTime> recordMap
  ) {
    // Do Logic (Removed for Brevity)

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
      new WithoutSharing().updateObjRecords(list);
    }
  }

  private without sharing class WithoutSharing {
    public void updateObjRecords(
      List<OBJ_A__c> lstRecordsToUpdate
    ) {
      update lstRecordsToUpdate;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i definitely use Inner Classes declared `without sharing` to elevate privileges so I doubt it is inner class-specific. Does the running user have Read permission on the object and FLS on the lookup field?

Comment: @cropredy the user has Read/Edit access to the object being updated by the DML, the object is the child of a master-detail with Account as the Master, so the lookup is accessible to them by definition. The user also has Read/Edit to Accounts, Accounts are OWD Private, and sharing rules grant the User Read-Only access to this particular account (and therefore, the detail records). The use case is that, upon saving a Call__c record to the Account, apex should update some details on the detail object (OBJ_A__c).

Comment: Note that criteria-based sharing rules aren't evaluated / considered in test methods. Could this be it?

Comment: @cropredy this is failing in a manual test via UI while logged in as the user. I've just noticed that there's another lookup relationship on the object in question, and the user doesn't have FLS/OLS to that lookup / object... however my understanding is that shouldn't matter when using w/o sharing, am I wrong there?

Comment: Updating requires obtaining locks on related parent objects.  It is an easy experiment for you to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, this issue actually ended up being completely unrelated to the code and was instead a Sandbox data issue. Some of the required lookup fields had values populated which didn't exist anymore, resulting in the error.